# Wiping hard drives in an IBM DS3512

Tags: raid, hard-drive, hardware-raid, ibm, sas

I have an IBM [DS3512](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/storage/disk/ds3500/) RAID storage device, which I'm planning to sell. How would I reliably wipe my data off of all the hard drives?

As far as I can tell, it abstracts away all direct access to the drives, so running a data wipe program on the RAID partitions wouldn't necessarily work. The only option I see is to manually remove each drive, attach it as an external drive via a SAS-to-USB adapter, and wipe it that way. Is there a better option?

Comment: A lot of arrays have a 'wipe data' option where the controller heads ensure a good job, don't know that model but take a look. Otherwise crush/burn them if you're really bothered.

Comment: Yes, but it's IBM, so I'd have to pay several hundred dollars more to "unlock" that feature. I don't want to invest in horrible hardware and software that I'm getting rid of.

Comment: Is that true? if so then wow - that sucks

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what this enclosure was connected so, I'm going to make some assumptions.

- If you were connected to a RAID controller, just delete the logical drives/virtual drives/RAID groups. That's usually good enough.
- Your RAID controller may also have an option to wipe the drives.
- Also, SAS-to-USB adapters don't exist.

Otherwise, this is too much effort. I don't bother anything beyond the above.

Comment: You seem to be correct about no SAS-to-USB. I was thinking about SATA-to-USB, but apparently going SAS->SATA->USB won't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Some common methods, you have to see what your model supports:

- Export all drives as JBOD. You'll end up with `n` drives you can wipe separately.
- Export them as RAIDx with max capacity, again without a spare. If you see a drive with the expected capacity in the OS, wiping this should also destroy all data.
- See if the controller offers a specific feature for data wiping.
- Sell only the case without drives if you are really concerned.